# viewing everybody connected to my network

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu 12.04 right now. I am wondering if there is an app that lets me view everybody connected to the network I am connected to with their computer name and IP address. And also if possible, I would like to search names of computers and get their ip address or the other way around. If there is any app that will satisfy all my needs, then perfect. If not, I would like to get the searching feature most of all. I am a new user to Ubuntu and I do not know English that well. So please, excuse my errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netdiscover`

Install with command
`sudo apt-get install netdiscover`

Usage is `sudo netdiscover -r xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy`

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is you network and `yy` is subnet.

also you can use `arp-scan`
Install with command
`sudo apt-get install arp-scan`

Usage is `sudo arp-scan -local`

You will be got output like this in netdiscover

[image]

Linux do not provide NetBIOS name but if you have `samba` installed on you PC
you can use `smbtree` to see win shares and mashines on local network.
Output is some thing like this

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, but they don't let me search users. plus, when i type in `arp-scan` I get this message `pcap_lookupdev: no suitable device found`. what can i do

Comment: `sudo arp-scan -local --interface eth0` You can change eth0 with your interface name

Comment: You can see your nic cards with command `ifconfig`, you will see ip addr and mask. With command `route` you will see your gateway

Comment: is there any way that i can get their ip adress using their hostname from `smbtree`?

Comment: `sudo nmblookup -A NetBOIS_name_of_PC`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with [nmap](http://nmap.org/) or it's graphical equivalent [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) you can get both in ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install nmap` and `sudo apt-get install zenmap`

Comment: Could you also add how i could use them please?

Comment: http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html, http://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/